# Django Order Ascending & Descending

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let say, I want to order the `Threads` by total `Votes`, `Views` and `Comments`. But they **order** models is instanced from `Thread` model.

[image: django oder]

here is my `models.py`

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    ....
    rating = RatingField(can_change_vote=True)

    def get_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(thread__pk=self.pk)

    def get_visitors(self):
        return Visitor.objects.filter(thread__pk=self.pk)

    def get_rating_frequence(self):
        return self.rating.get_difference()

class Comment(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, ...)
    ....

class Visitor(models.Model):
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread, ...)
    ....
```

and the model of `Vote` using [django updown](https://github.com/weluse/django-updown)

For more: https://github.com/weluse/django-updown/blob/master/updown/models.py#L20

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name="updown_votes")
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ....
```

And here is my `views.py`

```
def threads(request):
    ....
    template_name = 'foo/bar/threads.html'
    threads = Thread.objects.published()

    get_sorted_ratings = request.GET.get('sr', '')
    get_sorted_visitors = request.GET.get('sv', '')
    get_sorted_comments = request.GET.get('sc', '')

    context = {
        'threads': threads,
        ....
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Question is, how i can order multiple models bassed on `Thread` model?
In my test:

```
>>> from django.db.models import (Q, Count, Sum)
>>> from myapp.models import (Thread, Comment, Visitor)
>>> t = Thread.objects.published()
>>> Visitor.objects.filter(thread__in=t).values('thread').annotate(visit=Count('thread__id')).order_by('-visit')
<QuerySet [{'thread': 3, 'visit': 8}, {'thread': 10, 'visit': 8}, {'thread': 9, 'visit': 7}, {'thread': 48, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 57, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 79, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 103, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 104, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 132, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 178, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 216, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 227, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 267, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 292, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 300, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 305, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 1201, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 1252, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 1265, 'visit': 1}, {'thread': 1929, 'visit': 1}]>
>>> 
>>> Comment.objects.filter(thread__in=t).values('thread').annotate(total=Count('thread__id')).order_by('-total')
<QuerySet [{'total': 9, 'thread': 10}, {'total': 7, 'thread': 9}, {'total': 3, 'thread': 3}, {'total': 3, 'thread': 213}, {'total': 2, 'thread': 35}, {'total': 2, 'thread': 47}, {'total': 2, 'thread': 104}, {'total': 2, 'thread': 187}, {'total': 2, 'thread': 233}, {'total': 2, 'thread': 235}, {'total': 2, 'thread': 304}, {'total': 1, 'thread': 34}, {'total': 1, 'thread': 68}, {'total': 1, 'thread': 82}, {'total': 1, 'thread': 95}, {'total': 1, 'thread': 137}, {'total': 1, 'thread': 216}, {'total': 1, 'thread': 231}, {'total': 1, 'thread': 244}, {'total': 1, 'thread': 253}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
>>> 
>>> # rating likes, id=thread.id, total=total rating
>>> t.values('id').annotate(total=Sum('rating_likes')).order_by('-total')
<QuerySet [{'total': 3, 'id': 10}, {'total': 2, 'id': 104}, {'total': 2, 'id': 233}, {'total': 2, 'id': 235}, {'total': 2, 'id': 304}, {'total': 1, 'id': 3}, {'total': 1, 'id': 9}, {'total': 1, 'id': 34}, {'total': 1, 'id': 35}, {'total': 1, 'id': 47}, {'total': 1, 'id': 68}, {'total': 1, 'id': 82}, {'total': 1, 'id': 95}, {'total': 1, 'id': 137}, {'total': 1, 'id': 187}, {'total': 1, 'id': 213}, {'total': 1, 'id': 216}, {'total': 1, 'id': 231}, {'total': 1, 'id': 244}, {'total': 1, 'id': 253}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
>>> 
>>> # rating dislikes, id=thread.id, total=total rating
>>> t.values('id').annotate(total=Sum('rating_dislikes')).order_by('-total')
<QuerySet [{'total': 2, 'id': 3}, {'total': 1, 'id': 9}, {'total': 1, 'id': 10}, {'total': 1, 'id': 35}, {'total': 1, 'id': 47}, {'total': 1, 'id': 187}, {'total': 0, 'id': 29}, {'total': 0, 'id': 34}, {'total': 0, 'id': 42}, {'total': 0, 'id': 45}, {'total': 0, 'id': 48}, {'total': 0, 'id': 51}, {'total': 0, 'id': 53}, {'total': 0, 'id': 57}, {'total': 0, 'id': 68}, {'total': 0, 'id': 72}, {'total': 0, 'id': 75}, {'total': 0, 'id': 76}, {'total': 0, 'id': 77}, {'total': 0, 'id': 79}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
>>>
>>> Thread.objects.get(pk=3).rating.dislikes
2
>>> Thread.objects.get(pk=9).rating.dislikes
1
>>>
```

---

**Finally, I updated it:** and my code is worked well as what already suggested by @prakhar-trivedi at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775990/6396981

```
threads = Thread.objects.published()

def sorted_threads(values, order_by='-total', next_order=None):
    """
    return sorted threads from values by `order_by`
    :param `values`, an example:
        values = Comment.objects.filter(thread__in=threads)
                        .values('thread').annotate(total=Count('thread__id'))
    """
    if next_order is not None:
        top_values = values.order_by(order_by).order_by(next_order)
    else:
        top_values = values.order_by(order_by)
    list_pk_threads = [pk['thread'] for pk in top_values]
    filter_threads = list(threads.filter(pk__in=list_pk_threads))
    return sorted(filter_threads, key=lambda i: list_pk_threads.index(i.pk))
```

For complete stuff found at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/agusmakmun/b24762e737574d3962e03f07ded527ad).

> ***But***, I just don't know how to combine it at all.
>
> ***For example:*** ordering from `votes=1`, `views=1`, `comments=1`.
>   And the result of it is; the **Thread Objects** that ordered from popular by ***votes***, popular by ***views*** and also from popular by ***comments***.
>
> ***Another example:*** ordering from `votes=1` `views=1`.
>   The output of this condition should return the **Thread Objects** that ordered only from popular by ***votes***, and popular by ***views***.
>
> `1` as `True` and `-1` as `False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **order_by('-thread')**, like this :

```
Comment.objects.filter(thread__in=t).values('thread').annotate(total=Count('thread__id')).order_by('-thread')
```

And if you want to order records by **rating** of **thread** model,You can use  double underscore "__" on thread key for foreign key lookup,
like this :

```
# rating likes

Comment.objects.filter(thread__in=t).values('thread').annotate(total=Count('thread__id')).order_by('thread__rating_likes')
```

Use this in all your queries as per the requirements.

Comment: it only two models, how about three or more models..?
for example in my filter sorted from `request.GET.get('sr', '')` and `request.GET.get('sv', '')` and also `request.GET.get('sc', '')`..

Comment: @SancaKembang foreign key lookup with __ is like chaining,if used with correct suntax,it can be used as many times as you need.

Comment: @SancaKembang For example ,if thread model has a field rating which is foregin key of another model with filed voteCount then you can use **thread__rating__voteCount**.